# How could search for records through your relationship records? with scope in laravel

Tags: laravel

How would you search for records by your (records) with which you have a relationship?
Using scope.

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search_option, $search) {
if($search_option != null) {
return $query->where("$search_option", 'LIKE', "%$search%");
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is not that clear. Could you provide an example of what do you expect to receive as a result?

Comment: Of course, I want to do is be able to search for registers from a table called (products), through its relationship with category.

in such a way that you can search for a product by its category.

How could I perform that search using a scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $field, $searchTerm)
{
    $query->when($field, function ($query) use ($field, $searchTerm) {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($field, $searchTerm) {
            $query->where($field, 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%");
        });
    });
}
```

The `when()` clause is to only apply the filter if `$field` is set. Then we use `whereHas()` to filter products based on the category they have according to the specified filter (field/searchTerm).

Comment: Thank you very much Kenny Horna, your solution works very well, I really appreciate it.